# How to limit URL length using htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url

I am hosting wordpress website on my linux server. How can I limit the length of URLs from htaccess file.

Suppose if I do not want to allow more than 100 characters as URL. What options can I use in order to limit the allowed number of characters in the URL?.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> `Suppose if i donot want to allow more than 100 characters as URL`

This is unusual requirement to have but still can be handled by Rewrite rule.

Have this rule as your first rule:

```
RewriteRule ^.{101,}$ - [F]
```

Comment: will that break the original url? or does that have issues with SEO? thanks

Comment: This rule is not changing anything, it is just blocking URL of > 100 characters in length.

Comment: Thanks Abubhava. that is cool. I believe it won't hurt SEO in any manner.

Comment: No it won't. Unusually long URLs are only generated from spammers so blocking them will have no consequence on SEO rankings.